# Задать условие кнопкам

Tags: jquery

В форме есть три кнопки. Необходимо задать условие к каждой. Если нажата кнопка лайк, то  `action = like` и т.д.

Comment: так а в чем проблема?

Comment: используйте `data`-атрибуты

Comment: Нужен аналог isset php

Answer (score 1):

Значение по `value`:

```js
$('form input').on('click', function(){
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="button" data-action="like" value="like"> 
  <input type="button" data-action="vk" value="vk"> 
  <input type="button" data-action="twit" value="twit"> 
</form>
```

Значение по [пользовательскому аттрибуту](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/atribut-data) `data-action`:

```js
$('form input').on('click', function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('data-action'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="button" data-action="like" value="like"> 
  <input type="button" data-action="vk" value="vk"> 
  <input type="button" data-action="twit" value="twit"> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно обойтись без js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="handler.php" method="GET">
        <button type="submit" name="action" value="one">Один</button>
        <button type="submit" name="action" value="two">Два</button>
        <button type="submit" name="action" value="three">Три</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```